# Using VBA to count number of unhidden (visible) worksheets to the left of the active sheet (excel)?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a questionnaire within excel, and have been asked to include a "You are on sheet X out of Y" type indicator on each page.

The number of visible sheets varies depending on answer to some of the early quesitons (irrelevant question sets are hidden, etc.), as such both the numerator and denominator in that statement are variables.

I've got a label (Label1) on each page which I can write the caption of, I've managed to count the total number of visible sheets and tie the caption writing to the sheet activation event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
If Range("AZ1").Value = "1" Then

    Dim v
    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If s.Visible Then v = v + 1
    Next s
    ActiveSheet.Label1.Caption = "Currently viewing page X of " & v & vbCrLf

End If
End Sub
```

This correctly writes a denominator into each label on each sheet.

In order to find the numerator though, I need to be able to find the number of unhidden sheets to the left of the active sheet.

Does anyone know how I might do this using VBA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Worksheet.Index`-Property helps you out here:

```
Dim n As Long
Dim i As Long

n = 0
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Index
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Visible Then 
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next

Debug.Print n
```